# Streaming an instrument with a 6.35mm AUX stereo output

Tags: mixer, usb, digital, conversion, adapters

I have a beautiful [AvantGrand N2](https://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical_instruments/pianos/avantgrand/n2/index.html), Yahama's digital piano with acoustic action. I would like to use it to livestream a performance in a few weeks, seeing as I can't invite anyone over for a concert these days...

This machine has both two 6.35mm headphone outputs and, more importantly, a stereo AUX IN and OUT. Both of these are pairs of 6.35mm female ports labeled (L/L+R and R). (There's also a MIDI output, but I don't think that helps us here.)

[image]

The question is whether AUX OUT can be adapted to a digital signal ingested by a computer, presumably through a USB port. Googling around, I see plenty of males-to-male adaptors for 6.35mm stereo to 3.5mm mono, [like this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/3-5mm-Stereo-6-35mm-Audio-Cable/dp/B0034DSUMK/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=6.35+aux+to+usb&qid=1587848193&s=receiver-speakers&sr=1-1), as well as [3.5mm female-to-USB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0828J36JD) adaptors.

So in theory, I could plug the first chord into the AUX OUT, converting it to a mono 3.5mm, and then connect that to the USB adaptor. However, this raises and important question: **Are these adaptors bidirectional??**

As best I can tell, for example, the first cord is intended to connect a device with a 3.5mm output, like a laptop or a phone, into the AUX IN of a large amplifier. I'm not at all certain if it's able to work the other way as well. Further, the 3.5mm jack on a computer is, I believe, only an output, which is why the 3.5-to-USB is necessary. But again, I'm not certain it's really meant to inject sound/data INTO the computer so much as convert it from digital to analog on the way out.

It seems like there must be a mechanism for digitizing a 6.35 AUX OUT for a live broadcast or high-fidelity recording. I can live with a mono connection, which would still be better than micing the piano. I live near a fire station, so it would be wonderful not to pick up sirens during the performance!

**EDIT**: Googling some more, it looks like perhaps I need a simple mixer? It seems like most mixers accept AUX IN, but I can't tell whether some easily provide a digital output, or if that requires a second device. Most of what I've read refers to "Aux Sends."

Comment: you need a simple 4 channel USB interface, two 1/4" jack connectors for the keyboard and another channel for a mic.

Comment: Could I trouble you for a link to an example of a simple 4-channel USB interface? My Googling turns up options all over the price map. Thank you!

Comment: Behringer UMC404HD - if you can find one.

Comment: Thanks! Looks doable and is available on Amazon